# Export specific mysql tables to excel in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export

I have to export three specific tables to an Excel sheet, but all the data is pretty much dumped in one field, creating a large mess. Is it be possible to export the content of the three tables AND format them in Excel through PHP? Basically so that I could get:

```
Date:            Subject             Participants
Start - End      Subject Title       User 1
                                     User 2
                                     User 3
```

Basically so that everything is like that? To make it clear and visible (though this might cause issues with larger numbers of participants).

Also, I'll share my code, maybe someone can see what I'm messing up this time.

```
    <div id="tableform">
        <form method="post">
            <table class="nostyle">
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="startDate">Begin datum:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="date" id="BeginDate" name="BeginDate" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="startDate" name="startDate" value="<?= $startdate; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><label for="endDate">Eind datum:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="date" id="EindDate" name="EindDate" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="endDate" value="<?= $enddate; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="generate" value="Jaarverslag genereren"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And the function:

```
<?php
public function generateReport($startDate = null, $endDate = null) {
    if (empty($startDate) && empty($endDate)) {
        $time = strtotime("-1 year", time());
        $startDate = date("Y-m-d", $time);
        $endDate = date("Y-m-d");
    }
    $this->generator->create('Jaaroverzicht-' . $startDate . '-' . $endDate);
    $data = array(
        "Datum" . '' . "Aanwezigen" . '' . "Bijscholing"
    );
    foreach ($this->dbSchooling->getYearReport($startDate, $endDate) as $row) {
        $users = "";
        $participants = $this->dbSchooling->getParticipants($row['bijscholing_id']);
        foreach ($participants as $participant) {
            $users .= $participant;
            if ($participant == end($participants)) {
                $users .= ', ';
            }
        }
        $myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['bijscholing_begindatum']);
        $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
        array_push($data, ($newDateString . "." . $users . "." . '.' . $row['bijscholing_titel']));
    }
    foreach ($data as $line) {
        $this->generator->store(explode('.', $line));
    }
    return $this->generator->close();
} ?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything to do with excel there. Are you generating a csv using `.` as the separator? and if you're simply going to explode on that `.` afterwards anyways. why even bother generating a "dotsv" string in the first place> just put your fields into an array: `$arr[] = array($newDateString, $users, etc....);`

Comment: Can you give a sample on how the data is looking in the beginning? Hard work to follow your code backwards just to see where we actually are starting. Are you currently able to export data to excel or is this also something you need from us?

Comment: "would it be possible to export the content of the three tables AND format them in excel through PHP" No, Excel is Software on the client - your pc. You would have to format the data IN PHP and THEN export it to Excel or the other way around -> just throw data into excel and let your user format it, on his pc, then upload it to your webserver and do whatever you want

Comment: Hey guys. Philipp, at the moment the data is in fact exported to Excel, so when I press Generate I automatically download an excel sheet with all the required information (Dates, users and subject). The problem is that it's not automatically sorted in the proper format.

Marc B, I think that array might actually work. Just gotta find a way to make it work. Are you saying the explode function is messing up the format? Maybe I just need to remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has been edited to use semicolons.

```
public function generateReport($startDate = null, $endDate = null) {
    if(empty($startDate) && empty($endDate)) {
        $time = strtotime("-1 year", time());
        $startDate = date("Y-m-d", $time);
        $endDate = date("Y-m-d");
    }
    /**
     * Title
     */
    $this->generator->create('Jaaroverzicht-'. $startDate . '-'. $endDate);
    $data = array(
        "Datum;Bijscholing;Instructeur;Aanwezigen"
    );
    /**
     * Kopstukken + inhoud
     */
    foreach($this->dbSchooling->getYearReport($startDate, $endDate) as $row) {
        $users = "";
        $participants = $this->dbSchooling->getParticipantsVoornaam($row['bijscholing_id']);
        foreach($participants as $participant) {
            $users .= $participant;
            if($participant !== end($participants)) {
                $users .= ', ';
            }
        }
        $myDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['bijscholing_begindatum']);
        $newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d-m-Y');
        array_push($data, ($newDateString . ";" . $row['bijscholing_titel'] . " ; " . $row['bijscholing_presentator'] . ' ; ' . $users));
    }
    foreach ($data as $line)
    {
        $this->generator->store(explode(';', $line));
    }
    return $this->generator->close();
}
```

The encountered problem was only in a specific version of Excel. The file is correctly configured in Open Office Calc. By using a semicolon as a seperator it was easy to figure out the rest. Hope this helps anyone else with similar issues.